# Why does erasure complicate implementing function types?

Tags: java, generics, language-design, type-erasure

I read from an [interview with Neal Gafter](http://www.infoq.com/articles/neal-gafter-on-java):

> "For example, adding function types to the programming language is much more difficult with Erasure as part of Generics."

EDIT:
Another place where I've met similar statement was in Brian Goetz's [message in Lambda Dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-August/003877.html), where he says that lambdas are easier to handle when they are just anonymous classes with syntactic sugar:

> But my objection to function types was not that I don't like function types -- I love function types -- but that function types fought badly with an existing aspect of the Java type system, erasure.  Erased function types are the worst of both worlds. So we removed this from the design.

Can anyone explain these statements? Why would I need runtime type information with lambdas?

Comment: this would be better answered on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: great question - I have been wondering the same thing after Goetz's comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I understand it, is that they decided that thanks to erasure it would be messy to go the way of '**function types**', e.g. *delegates* in C# and they only could use **lambda expressions**, which is just a simplification of *single abstract method* class syntax.

Delegates in C#:

```
public delegate void DoSomethingDelegate(Object param1, Object param2);
...
//now assign some method to the function type variable (delegate)
DoSomethingDelegate f = DoSomething;
f(new Object(), new Object());
```

(another sample here
http://geekswithblogs.net/joycsharp/archive/2008/02/15/simple-c-delegate-sample.aspx)

One argument they put forward in Project Lambda docs:

> Generic types are erased, which would expose additional places where
>   developers are exposed to erasure. For example, it would not be
>   possible to overload methods m(T->U) and m(X->Y), which would be
>   confusing.

section 2 in:
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-3.html

(The final lambda expressions syntax will be a bit different from the above document:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/003936.html)

```
(x, y) => { System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", x, y, x+y); }
```

All in all, my best understanding is that only a part of syntax stuff that could, actually will be used. 
What Neal Gafter most likely meant was that not being able to use delegates will make standard APIs more difficult to adjust to functional style, rather than that javac/JVM update would be more difficult to be done.

If someone understands this better than me, I will be happy to read his account.

Comment: Method overloading on generics of parameters is an orthogonal issue to runtime reification, contrary to certain incorrect assertions. IMO, there's enough overloading going on without complicating the language with more (and it is well known that Java generic type system is not that simple).

Comment: @MarianP So you mean that function types would be just another reason to complain about type erasure?

Comment: Yes. Make developers complain/confuse them even more. At least from I gather.

Comment: Also covered here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ldn3/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: Interestingly enough, Scala does support function types, and gives a compiler error if you try to define overloaded methods that take function typed parameters.

Comment: @ericacm Maybe we should all go Scala, Java seems to be reaching its limits thanks to trying to preserve the most of compatibility in between versions. It had huge benefits, but...

Answer (score 2):

Goetz expands on the reasoning in [State of the Lambda 4th ed.](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html):

> An alternative (or complementary) approach to function types,
>   suggested by some early proposals, would have been to introduce a new,
>   structural function type. A type like "function from a String and an
>   Object to an int" might be expressed as (String,Object)->int. This
>   idea was considered and rejected, at least for now, due to several
>   disadvantages:
>
> - It would add complexity to the type system and further mix structural and nominal types.
> - It would lead to a divergence of library styles—some libraries would continue to use callback interfaces, while others would use structural
>     function types.
> - The syntax could be unweildy, especially when checked exceptions were included.
> - It is unlikely that there would be a runtime representation for each distinct function type, meaning developers would be further exposed to
>     and limited by erasure. For example, it would not be possible (perhaps
>     surprisingly) to overload methods m(T->U) and m(X->Y).
>
> So, we have instead chosen to take the path of "use what you
>   know"—since existing libraries use functional interfaces extensively,
>   we codify and leverage this pattern.
>
> To illustrate, here are some of the functional interfaces in Java SE 7
>   that are well-suited for being used with the new language features;
>   the examples that follow illustrate the use of a few of them.
>
> - java.lang.Runnable
> - java.util.concurrent.Callable
> - java.util.Comparator
> - java.beans.PropertyChangeListener
> - java.awt.event.ActionListener
> - javax.swing.event.ChangeListener
> - ...

Note that erasure is just one of the considerations.  In general, the Java lambda approach goes in a different direction from Scala, not just on the typed question.  It's very Java-centric.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because what you'd really want would be a type `Function<R, P...>`, which is parameterised with a return type and some sequence of parameter types. But because of erasure, you can't have a construct like `P...`, because it could only turn into `Object[]`, which is too loose to be much use at runtime.

This is pure speculation. I am not a type theorist; i haven't even played one on TV.

Comment: Do you mean P... like in varargs notation? So it would mean an array of types?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is a hypothetical notation, but one you would need to handle function types with a single generic type, because functions have varying numbers of parameters.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have a generic type for all functions with arbitrary arity.

Comment: Well, you can't have a generic type for functions of each particular arity, because you'd need an infinite number of them. If you want a generic type at all, you have to have exactly one. Because we don't have anything like `P...`, we can't have just one. So, no, it doesn't make sense to have a generic type for all functions with arbitrary arity. That's rather my point!

Comment: "If you want a generic type at all, you have to have exactly one". I don't think so :)

Comment: I meant a generic type for functions. How many of those do you think we need?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean -- single nominal type for functions. I don't think it's feasible. First of all, function types seem to be most naturally expressed as structural types ie. you use type *expressions* instead of type names eg. "Int -> Int" or "(Int, String) -> List<String>". The closest that's possible with Java type system seems to be generic types "Function<ArgT1, ArgT2 ,..., RetT>", one for each arity. But the real topic at the moment is that Java can only express types of objects, not functions. If functions are represented by objects (as currently proposed), then it works

Answer (score -1):

I think what he means in that statement is that at runtime Java cannot tell the difference between these two function definitions:

```
void doIt(List<String> strings) {...}
void doIt(List<Integer> ints) {...}
```

Because at compile time, the information about what type of data the List contains is erased, so the runtime environment wouldn't be able to determine which function you wanted to call.

Trying to compile both of these methods in the same class will throw the following exception:

```
doIt(List<String>) clashes with doIt(List<Integer); both methods have the same erasure
```

Comment: -1 This has nothing to do with the question. The comment is on *function types* (ie: [higher order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)).

Comment: It answers the question he was asking about why generics makes function typing more difficult.

Comment: That's not what the question asks. Function types `!=` Function (method) typing

Comment: The question of those two methods being able to overload is a compile-time issue.

Comment: @Anthony, your first comment is coming across as pretty condescending, considering the lack of "proper understanding" seems to be yours--would you consider editing or removing it?

Comment: I recognize that I misread the question. There was a comment that NullUserException posted and deleted which incorrectly stating that java would be able to tell the difference between those two functions, and they would not cause a compile time issue.